# Import code style settings from checkstyle.xml, but the format code does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, format, code-formatting, checkstyle

I imported `checkstyle.xml` into IntelliJ IDEA, but the format didn't take effect. To be precise, it didn't take effect at all. What's wrong with my operation?

I imported the `checkstyle.xml`  like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/suppressions.xml"/>
    </module>

    <module name="SuppressWithPlainTextCommentFilter">
        <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE\:OFF\:(\w+)"/>
        <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE\:ON\:(\w+)"/>
        <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
    </module>

    <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"/>

    <module name="SeverityMatchFilter">
        <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        <property name="acceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
    </module>

    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>

    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="max" value="120"/>
        <property name="ignorePattern" value="^[ \t]*\*.*@.*$"/>
    </module>

    <module name="Header">
        <property name="header" value="/*\n * Copyright 2014-2022 Real Logic Limited."/>
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    </module>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
        <property name="severity" value="error"/>

        <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/>

        <module name="MissingJavadocType"/>
        <module name="MissingJavadocMethod"/>
        <module name="MissingJavadocPackage"/>

        <module name="Indentation">
            <property name="forceStrictCondition" value="true"/>
        </module>

        <module name="ConstantName"/>

        <module name="FinalParameters">
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_CATCH, FOR_EACH_CLAUSE"/>
        </module>

        <module name="FinalLocalVariable">
            <property name="validateEnhancedForLoopVariable" value="true"/>
        </module>

        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>

        <module name="LocalVariableName"/>

        <module name="MemberName">
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"/>
        </module>

        <module name="MethodName"/>

        <module name="PackageName"/>

        <module name="ParameterName"/>

        <module name="StaticVariableName"/>

        <module name="TypeName">
            <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"/>
        </module>

        <module name="RedundantImport"/>

        <module name="UnusedImports"/>

        <module name="MethodLength">
            <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF"/>
            <property name="max" value="100"/>
        </module>

        <module name="EmptyForInitializerPad"/>

        <module name="MethodParamPad"/>

        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>

        <module name="WhitespaceAfter">
            <property name="tokens" value="COMMA, SEMI, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, DO_WHILE"/>
        </module>

        <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
            <property name="tokens" value="INC, DEC, UNARY_MINUS, UNARY_PLUS, BNOT, LNOT, DOT, TYPECAST, ARRAY_DECLARATOR, INDEX_OP, METHOD_REF"/>
            <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="false"/>
        </module>

        <module name="WhitespaceAround">
            <property name="allowEmptyLambdas" value="true"/>
        </module>

        <module name="SingleSpaceSeparator"/>

        <module name="OperatorWrap">
            <property name="option" value="eol"/>
        </module>

        <module name="NeedBraces"/>

        <module name="ParenPad"/>

        <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>

        <module name="ModifierOrder"/>

        <module name="RedundantModifier"/>

        <module name="NestedTryDepth">
            <property name="max" value="2"/>
        </module>

        <module name="CovariantEquals"/>

        <module name="LeftCurly">
            <property name="option" value="nl"/>
        </module>

        <module name="RightCurly">
            <property name="option" value="alone"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT"/>
        </module>

        <module name="EmptyStatement"/>

        <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>

        <module name="DefaultComesLast"/>

        <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>

        <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>

        <module name="StringLiteralEquality"/>

        <module name="PackageDeclaration"/>

        <module name="FallThrough"/>

        <module name="FinalClass"/>

        <module name="MutableException"/>

        <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF"/>
        </module>

        <module name="TodoComment">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
            <property name="format" value="TODO"/>
        </module>

        <module name="UpperEll"/>

        <module name="IllegalType">
            <property name="legalAbstractClassNames"
                      value="AbstractBeanDefinition, AbstractEntry"/>
            <property name="illegalClassNames"
                      value="java.util.GregorianCalendar, java.util.Vector"/>
        </module>

        <module name="DescendantToken">
            <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_ASSERT"/>
            <property name="limitedTokens"
                      value="ASSIGN,DEC,INC,POST_DEC,POST_INC,PLUS_ASSIGN,MINUS_ASSIGN,STAR_ASSIGN,DIV_ASSIGN,MOD_ASSIGN,BSR_ASSIGN,SR_ASSIGN,SL_ASSIGN,BAND_ASSIGN,BXOR_ASSIGN,BOR_ASSIGN,METHOD_CALL"/>
            <property name="maximumNumber" value="2"/>
        </module>

        <module name="Regexp">
            <property name="format" value="[ \t]+$"/>
            <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
            <property name="message" value="Trailing whitespace"/>
        </module>

        <module name="JavadocMethod"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

[imported checkstyle.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiQam.png)

and I got the editorconfig

```
[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = false
max_line_length = 120
tab_width = 4
ij_continuation_indent_size = 8
ij_formatter_off_tag = @formatter:off
ij_formatter_on_tag = @formatter:on
ij_formatter_tags_enabled = false
ij_smart_tabs = false
ij_visual_guides = none
ij_wrap_on_typing = false
...

[*.java]
ij_continuation_indent_size = 4
ij_java_align_consecutive_assignments = false
ij_java_align_consecutive_variable_declarations = false
ij_java_align_group_field_declarations = false
ij_java_align_multiline_annotation_parameters = false
ij_java_align_multiline_array_initializer_expression = false
ij_java_align_multiline_assignment = false
ij_java_align_multiline_binary_operation = false
ij_java_align_multiline_chained_methods = false
ij_java_align_multiline_extends_list = false
ij_java_align_multiline_for = true
ij_java_align_multiline_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_align_multiline_parameters = true
ij_java_align_multiline_parameters_in_calls = false
ij_java_align_multiline_parenthesized_expression = false
ij_java_align_multiline_records = true
ij_java_align_multiline_resources = true
ij_java_align_multiline_ternary_operation = false
ij_java_align_multiline_text_blocks = false
ij_java_align_multiline_throws_list = false
ij_java_align_subsequent_simple_methods = false
ij_java_align_throws_keyword = false
ij_java_annotation_parameter_wrap = off
ij_java_array_initializer_new_line_after_left_brace = false
ij_java_array_initializer_right_brace_on_new_line = false
ij_java_array_initializer_wrap = normal
ij_java_assert_statement_colon_on_next_line = false
ij_java_assert_statement_wrap = normal
ij_java_assignment_wrap = normal
ij_java_binary_operation_sign_on_next_line = false
ij_java_binary_operation_wrap = normal
ij_java_blank_lines_after_anonymous_class_header = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_after_class_header = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_after_imports = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_after_package = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_class = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_field = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_around_field_in_interface = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_around_initializer = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_method = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_method_in_interface = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_before_class_end = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_before_imports = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_before_method_body = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_before_package = 0
ij_java_block_brace_style = next_line
ij_java_block_comment_at_first_column = true
ij_java_builder_methods = none
ij_java_call_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_call_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_call_parameters_wrap = normal
ij_java_case_statement_on_separate_line = true
ij_java_catch_on_new_line = false
ij_java_class_annotation_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_class_brace_style = next_line
ij_java_class_count_to_use_import_on_demand = 5
ij_java_class_names_in_javadoc = 1
ij_java_do_not_indent_top_level_class_members = false
ij_java_do_not_wrap_after_single_annotation = false
ij_java_do_while_brace_force = always
ij_java_doc_add_blank_line_after_description = true
ij_java_doc_add_blank_line_after_param_comments = false
ij_java_doc_add_blank_line_after_return = false
ij_java_doc_add_p_tag_on_empty_lines = true
ij_java_doc_align_exception_comments = true
ij_java_doc_align_param_comments = true
ij_java_doc_do_not_wrap_if_one_line = false
ij_java_doc_enable_formatting = true
ij_java_doc_enable_leading_asterisks = true
ij_java_doc_indent_on_continuation = false
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_lines = true
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_parameter_tag = true
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_return_tag = true
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_throws_tag = true
ij_java_doc_keep_invalid_tags = true
ij_java_doc_param_description_on_new_line = false
ij_java_doc_preserve_line_breaks = false
ij_java_doc_use_throws_not_exception_tag = true
ij_java_else_on_new_line = false
ij_java_entity_dd_suffix = EJB
ij_java_entity_eb_suffix = Bean
ij_java_entity_hi_suffix = Home
ij_java_entity_lhi_prefix = Local
ij_java_entity_lhi_suffix = Home
ij_java_entity_li_prefix = Local
ij_java_entity_pk_class = java.lang.String
ij_java_entity_vo_suffix = VO
ij_java_enum_constants_wrap = normal
ij_java_extends_keyword_wrap = normal
ij_java_extends_list_wrap = normal
ij_java_field_annotation_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_finally_on_new_line = false
ij_java_for_brace_force = always
ij_java_for_statement_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_for_statement_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_for_statement_wrap = normal
ij_java_generate_final_locals = false
ij_java_generate_final_parameters = false
ij_java_if_brace_force = always
ij_java_imports_layout = *,|,javax.**,java.**,|,$*
ij_java_indent_case_from_switch = true
ij_java_insert_inner_class_imports = false
ij_java_insert_override_annotation = true
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_before_right_brace = 2
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_between_package_declaration_and_header = 2
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_in_code = 2
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_in_declarations = 2
ij_java_keep_builder_methods_indents = false
ij_java_keep_control_statement_in_one_line = true
ij_java_keep_first_column_comment = true
ij_java_keep_indents_on_empty_lines = false
ij_java_keep_line_breaks = true
ij_java_keep_multiple_expressions_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_blocks_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_classes_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_lambdas_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_methods_in_one_line = false
ij_java_label_indent_absolute = false
ij_java_label_indent_size = 0
ij_java_lambda_brace_style = end_of_line
ij_java_layout_static_imports_separately = true
ij_java_line_comment_add_space = false
ij_java_line_comment_at_first_column = true
ij_java_message_dd_suffix = EJB
ij_java_message_eb_suffix = Bean
ij_java_method_annotation_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_method_brace_style = next_line
ij_java_method_call_chain_wrap = normal
ij_java_method_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_method_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_method_parameters_wrap = normal
ij_java_modifier_list_wrap = false
ij_java_names_count_to_use_import_on_demand = 3
ij_java_new_line_after_lparen_in_record_header = false
ij_java_packages_to_use_import_on_demand = java.awt.*,javax.swing.*
ij_java_parameter_annotation_wrap = normal
ij_java_parentheses_expression_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_parentheses_expression_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_place_assignment_sign_on_next_line = false
ij_java_prefer_longer_names = true
ij_java_prefer_parameters_wrap = false
ij_java_record_components_wrap = normal
ij_java_repeat_synchronized = true
ij_java_replace_instanceof_and_cast = false
ij_java_replace_null_check = true
ij_java_replace_sum_lambda_with_method_ref = true
ij_java_resource_list_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_resource_list_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_resource_list_wrap = normal
ij_java_rparen_on_new_line_in_record_header = false
ij_java_session_dd_suffix = EJB
ij_java_session_eb_suffix = Bean
ij_java_session_hi_suffix = Home
ij_java_session_lhi_prefix = Local
ij_java_session_lhi_suffix = Home
ij_java_session_li_prefix = Local
ij_java_session_si_suffix = Service
ij_java_space_after_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_argument = false
ij_java_space_after_colon = true
ij_java_space_after_comma = true
ij_java_space_after_comma_in_type_arguments = true
ij_java_space_after_for_semicolon = true
ij_java_space_after_quest = true
ij_java_space_after_type_cast = true
ij_java_space_before_annotation_array_initializer_left_brace = false
ij_java_space_before_annotation_parameter_list = false
ij_java_space_before_array_initializer_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_catch_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_catch_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_catch_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_class_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_colon = true
ij_java_space_before_colon_in_foreach = true
ij_java_space_before_comma = false
ij_java_space_before_do_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_else_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_else_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_finally_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_finally_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_for_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_for_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_for_semicolon = false
ij_java_space_before_if_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_if_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_java_space_before_method_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_parameter = false
ij_java_space_before_quest = true
ij_java_space_before_switch_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_switch_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_synchronized_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_synchronized_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_try_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_try_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_type_parameter_list = false
ij_java_space_before_while_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_while_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_while_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_inside_one_line_enum_braces = false
ij_java_space_within_empty_array_initializer_braces = false
ij_java_space_within_empty_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_java_space_within_empty_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_around_additive_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_assignment_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_bitwise_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_equality_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_lambda_arrow = true
ij_java_spaces_around_logical_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_method_ref_dbl_colon = false
ij_java_spaces_around_multiplicative_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_relational_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_shift_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_type_bounds_in_type_parameters = true
ij_java_spaces_around_unary_operator = false
ij_java_spaces_within_angle_brackets = false
ij_java_spaces_within_annotation_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_array_initializer_braces = false
ij_java_spaces_within_braces = false
ij_java_spaces_within_brackets = false
ij_java_spaces_within_cast_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_catch_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_for_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_if_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_record_header = false
ij_java_spaces_within_switch_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_synchronized_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_try_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_while_parentheses = false
ij_java_special_else_if_treatment = true
ij_java_subclass_name_suffix = Impl
ij_java_ternary_operation_signs_on_next_line = false
ij_java_ternary_operation_wrap = normal
ij_java_test_name_suffix = Test
ij_java_throws_keyword_wrap = normal
ij_java_throws_list_wrap = normal
ij_java_use_external_annotations = false
ij_java_use_fq_class_names = false
ij_java_use_relative_indents = false
ij_java_use_single_class_imports = true
ij_java_variable_annotation_wrap = normal
ij_java_visibility = public
ij_java_while_brace_force = always
ij_java_while_on_new_line = false
ij_java_wrap_comments = false
ij_java_wrap_first_method_in_call_chain = false
ij_java_wrap_long_lines = false
```

after that

I use `command +option + l` to format the file.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF5wp.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikd2Y.png)

Can anyone see where the problem is？  look like the format code doesn't work

Comment: Share the scheme you imported. Make sure editorconfig is not overriding your formatting options.

Comment: @CrazyCoder   Hi  ~ I updated the question, can you give me some advice

Comment: Does it help if you disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Enable EditorConfig support?